# Обновление выборки из таблицы django

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, которая подтягивает данные из таблицы. На следующей странице данные меняются. Однако, если вернуться на предыдущую страницу - изменения отображены не будут. Помогает только перезапуск сервера. 
Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что `CHOICES` фиксируются в момент создания и не обновляются после этого, при обновлении страницы с этой формой.
Подскажите, как обновить данные на странице без необходимости перезагружать сервер?

**forms.py**:

```
class ChooseRoute(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [(route.id,route.display_name()) for route in Schedule.objects.all()]
    choose_route = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=CHOICES)
    delete_route = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=(('Y','Yes'),('N','No')))
```

**views.py**:

```
def select_route(request):

    form = ChooseRoute()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'trains_schedule/route.html',context)
```

**route.html**:

```
<form action="change-data/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Change train route" />
</form>
```

Comment: Потому, что у вас `CHOICES` **статическая** переменная. Она будет инициализироваться 1 раз при запуске программы. У вас это могло бы работать, если бы вы в нее заносили изменения. Но все ровно так делать не стоит. В вашем ответе вы сделали `CHOICES` **не статической**, и вы перенесли инициализацию в конструктор, это нормальное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, код нужно изменить вот так чтобы работало:

views.py

```
def select_route(request):
    CHOICES = [(route.id,route.display_name()) for route in Schedule.objects.all()]
    form = ChooseRoute(choices=CHOICES)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'trains_schedule/select_route.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
class ChooseRoute(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        super(ChooseRoute,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['choose_route'].choices=self.choices
    choose_route = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    delete_route = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=(('Y','Yes'),('N','No')))
```

Соответственно добавляем аргумент при создании класса и передаем CHOICES туда - они будут обновляться каждый раз при обновлении страницы.